Why are Ozone features not working on Ubuntu Wayland?
I am currently using Ubuntu(with GNOME) on Wayland.
I'm trying to get a "smooth pinch-to-zoom" feature on Microsoft Edge.
The following works with plasma on Wayland:
microsoft-edge --enable-features=UseOzonePlatform --ozone-platform=wayland

But for some reason the above command doesn't enable the required feature on GNOME.
Could someone help me out with this?
